# SQL query to display latest value first and then others ASC

Tags: sql, sorting

I have a table with news which I then echo into a slider using foreach loop.
I would need to adjust the sort order of the query, so the last one added (max id) is always displayed first, with others sorted by id ASC.

So example: News 1, 2, 3,4. I need them echoed like 4,1,2,3.

```
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY sort ASC
```

How add another condition in the form of max(id) first then sort ASC?

Thanks.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (You've already got product specific answers, don't waste other peoples' time writing answers for "wrong" database.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *,
         (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM news) AS max_id 
   FROM news) AS t
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = max_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END asc,
         id ASC
```

or, using `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM news AS n
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(Id) AS max_id FROM news) AS m
ORDER BY CASE WHEN n.id = m.max_id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END asc,
         n.id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions, the CROSS JOIN method worked.

Answer (score 0):

or use window function

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS RN
    FROM news) AS T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *, MAX(id) OVER () AS MaxID
    FROM news) AS T
ORDER BY CASE WHEN MaxID = id THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id
```